# Using requestLocationUpdates for more than one provider

Tags: android, android-location

(this is about the `LocationManager` class in android).

Is there a way of using `requestLocationUpdates`, but in some way that allows it to give me results for the best active provider every time? I could pass it the result of `getBestProvider`, but then it will always return results from that provider, and it wouldn't work as I expect if the user turns the gps on/off.

My code is in a background service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way of using requestLocationUpdates, but in some way that allows it to give me results for the best active provider every time?

No, though you are welcome to register separate `LocationListeners` for multiple providers.

> I could pass it the result of getBestProvider, but then it will always return results from that provider, and it wouldn't work as I expect if the user turns the gps on/off.

Your `LocationListener` is notified when its provider is enabled and disabled. If your current provider is disabled, you might register a `LocationListener` with a backup provider.

Comment: Ok I made it work with different listeners using the enabled/disabled functions. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This is what I do:

```
public class LocationActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{

    private TextView latituteField;
    private TextView longitudeField;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String provider;
    private TextView outputField;
    private Location location;
    private ScrollView scrollView;
    private Criteria criteria;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_location);

        latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lat_textView);
        longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.long_textView);
        outputField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output_textView);
        scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);

        List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(criteria, true);
        outputField.append("Providers available..." + "\n");
        for (String provider : providers) {
            outputField.append(provider + "\n");
            scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
        }

        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);

        if (provider != null) {
            outputField.append("Provider " + provider + " has been selected." + "\n");
            scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);

            if (location != null) {
                onLocationChanged(location);
            } else {
                latituteField.setText("Location not available");
                longitudeField.setText("Location not available");
            }
          } else {
            outputField.append("No provider selected" + "\n");
            scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
          }
    }

    @Override
      protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
      }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
      }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        double lat =location.getLatitude();
        double lng =location.getLongitude();
        latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
        longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
        outputField.append("New Location: " + String.valueOf(lat) + " " + String.valueOf(lng) + "\n");
        scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String dProvider) {
        outputField.append("Provider " + dProvider + " has been disabled." + "\n");
        scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);

        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);

        if (provider != null) {
            outputField.append("Provider " + provider + " has been selected." + "\n");
            scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);

            if (location != null) {
                onLocationChanged(location);
            } else {
                latituteField.setText("Location not available");
                longitudeField.setText("Location not available");
            }
          } else {
            outputField.append("No provider selected" + "\n");
            scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
          }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String eProvider) {
        outputField.append("Provider " + eProvider + " has been enabled." + "\n");
        scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);

        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);

        if (provider != null) {
            outputField.append("Provider " + provider + " has been selected." + "\n");
            scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);

            if (location != null) {
                onLocationChanged(location);
            } else {
                latituteField.setText("Location not available");
                longitudeField.setText("Location not available");
            }
          } else {
            outputField.append("No provider selected" + "\n");
            scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
          }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        outputField.append("Provider " + provider + " status changed to: " + Integer.toString(status) + "\n");
        scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
    }
}
```

Comment: Solid gold my brother! Solid gold. Pity that no one up voted this answer!!

Comment: Showing error in  locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this); 
It is not being resolved..why?

Answer (score 0):

From API level 9 and onwards, this is possible, using this method:

```
requestLocationUpdates(long minTime, float minDistance, Criteria criteria, PendingIntent intent);
```

[See the documentation for more information on usage.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent))