# Location in android

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, location, android-location

I have used GPS in measuring distance traveled.The problem is GPS sometimes do not update location change for a long time.

Is there any solution for this?

```
    locationListen = new LocationListener() {

        public void onLocationChanged(Location currentLocation) {
            if (prevLocation != null){
                test = currentLocation.distanceTo(prevLocation);
                distance+=test;
            }
            prevLocation = currentLocation;

        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle b) {
            switch (status) {
            case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Status Changed: Out of Service " + provider,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
                Toast.makeText(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        "Status Changed: Temporarily Unavailable "
                                + provider, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Status Changed: Available " + provider,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
        }
    };

    startOperation.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View but) {
            if (startOperation.getText().equals("Start Calculating Fare")) {
                mHandler.post(run);
                myManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 10,
                                locationListen);
                startOperation.setText("Stop the calculations");
            } else {
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(run);
                myManager.removeUpdates(locationListen);
                finalInfos();
            }
        }
    });
```

My code for the location listener. It just update using GPS. As what I am saying the GPS is sometimes too long to detect a location

Comment: May GPS is not available at that place or may be the lat & long has not changed...

Comment: @SilentKiller I also think so, how can improve this? Any idea?

Comment: @hardikjoshi It's there.

Comment: @Xelamae in that case you can fetch CEllID from TelephonyManager API and from that cell id you can do reverse api call which will return you lat-lon of that cell-id. see this [link](http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/06/get-location-of-cell-id-from.html)

Comment: @Lucifer whether this give accurate result...???

Comment: @SilentKiller, ofcouse not, it will return the lat-lon of cell-tower, not device's

Comment: so brother how can i calculate the distance traveled..
its not fitting to requirement...!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are explicitly requesting a GPS-only location provider in your code. This forces Android to rely on GPS alone, with all of its drawbacks (GPS requires a clean view of the sky to work, for example).

To get a more reliable device tracking, you have to use a more reliable and flexible location strategy, changing the current location provider accordingly to the changed external scenario (indoor/outdoor, etc.). Even better, you could use a whole set of different location providers at the same time (that is: a "hybrid" positioning system).

Have a look at these previously answered SO questions:

[More than one location provider at same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9785768/more-than-one-location-provider-at-same-time)

[Using requestLocationUpdates for more than one provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150462/using-requestlocationupdates-for-more-than-one-provider)

And to these pages of the Android documentation:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/location/locationmanager.html

Comment: Can i just use getBestProvider()?

Comment: Yes and no. getBestProvider just gives your the location provider that currently best meet your criteria. These criteria are static: once declared, they remain always the same and so do the resulting location provider. Instead, you need a way to dynamically adapt to a changing scenario. This is why you have to deal with these changes in your code.